# I add new ssd for my old laptop is ubuntu when i select erase disk will automatically be installed on it or must do something else i don't want files

Tags: boot, server, ssd, windows-8, amavisd-new

I want to install Ubuntu without do anything to my new ssd disk.

Just erase all my data and boot Ubuntu on my ssd, not on my hdd.

Comment: Why else would it erase the disk ... It's an installer ... Yes, Ubuntu will automatically be installed on the selected disk after erasing it and will auto partition and occupy the whole disk. ... "erase disk" means exactly what it says and can be dangerous if the wrong disk is selected.

Comment: Okay that means ubuntu is smart to add its files engine on ssd not on hdd

Comment: But if I while installation type I select something else option that will delete my files on original old disk I don't want any data to be on old drive also if ubuntu not delete old data can I delete it after installation

Comment: Yes, you can even format the old HDD from within Ubuntu after installing it on the SSD.

Comment: I got this error /run/user/999 is not owned by us

Comment: Is that mean the ssd is invalid I just purchased it last two week

Comment: This error is be displayed with two installation type erase and something else

Comment: Know I continue but  Know I see install window with title everything you need for the office

Comment: Please see: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview for help

Comment: I did all that but now it's take a lot of time

Comment: I just wait in install window with title everything you need for the office and can use slider just mouse load and load why this time I think the new ssd is not valid

Comment: Last question please if I select hdd not ssd ubuntu will be installed on ssd

Comment: Some of the advice here applies to **`ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso`** and **`lubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso`** but not to for example `ubuntu-23.04-desktop-legacy-amd64.iso` and `xubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso`. Iso files with the installer Ubiquity will write the EFI boot structure into the first internal drive, while the new Ubuntu 23.04 and the current Lubuntu iso files have other installers that can focus completely on a second (for example external) drive. - If the installer does not 'see' the second or external drive, wipe it (remove the partition table) for example with **mkusb**.

Answer (score 0):

I have once cloned my hard disk to a brand new SSD of the same size by using a `dd` command.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4K status=progress
```

In my case it took 3,5 hours and it was successful. But beware not to make an error on the cloning direction!

The `if=` and `of=` designations were taken from the results of

```
sudo blkid
```

and I did it all with a system booted from a USB stick, because I wanted to be sure that neither the installed hard disk nor the installed SSD are mounted. None of the two file systems were mounted during this cloning operation. The number of sectors of the source and target were indentical.

If they differ, one would first have to re-size partitions on the source drive and then move partitions on the source device such that to be used content becomes consecutive (but there may be empty space within the partitions). It all has to fit to the target device.

The disadvantage of this approach is, that the partitions on the cloned hard disk have exactly the same UUIDs, and DiskLabels and so on as the original hard disk. On one hand this ist very good, because all references within the disks remain consistent. But on the other hand, having disks with identical UUIDs and DiskLabels bears much potential for destroying the content on the original hard disk and on its cloned image on the SSD!

Therefore I shut down the computer immediately after this cloning operation and physically removed the hard drive from it.

My hard disk originally had a swap partition (which actually does not make sense on a SSD). I re-sized other partitions to regain this space of the SSD later. Unfortunately I did not write down, how I achieved this step.